# Avoid indirect instantiation from private constructor through operation

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, private

I am trying to create a class whose objects must contain a short description ("name") of what their value represent. Therefore the only public constructor should take a string as argument.

For the operations, however, I need to create temporary (no relevant name) object to calculate the value to be assigned to an already existing object. For that I have implemented a private constructor, which should not be used, neither directly nor indirectly, to instantiate a new object - these temporary objects should only be assigned to an already existing object, through operator=,  which only copies the value rather than name and value.

The problem comes with the use of "auto". If a new variable is declared as follows:

```
auto newObj = obj + obj;
```

the compiler deduces the return type of operator+ and directly assign its result to `newObj`. This results in an object with a irrelevant name, which should not be possible to instantiate.

Also, deducing the type of an already existing object should still be possible from some functions, like:

```
auto newObj = obj.makeNewObjWithSameTypeButOtherName("Other name");
```

Follows a code demonstrating the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Sample
{
    public:
    Sample(const string&);

    Sample<T> makeNewObj(const string&);
    // Invalid constructors
    Sample();
    Sample(const Sample&);

    void operator=(const Sample&);
    void operator=(const T&);

    Sample<T> operator+(const Sample&) const;

    void show(void);

private:
// Private constructor used during operations
Sample(const T&);

T _value;
string _name;


};

template<class T>
Sample<T>::Sample(const string& name)
{
    this->_name = name;
    this->_value = 0;
}

template<class T>
Sample<T>::Sample(const T&value)
{
    this->_name = "Temporary variable";
    this->_value = value;
}

template<class T>
Sample<T>
Sample<T>::makeNewObj(const string& name)
{
    return Sample<T>(name);
}

template<class T>
void
Sample<T>::operator=(const Sample& si)
{
    this->_name = this->_name; // Make explicit: Never change the name
    this->_value = si._value;
}

template<class T>
void
Sample<T>::operator=(const T& value)
{
    this->_name = this->_name; // Make explicit: Never change the name
    this->_value = value;
}

template<class T>
Sample<T>
Sample<T>::operator+(const Sample& si) const
{
    // if any of the two values are invalid, throw some error
    return Sample<T>( this->_value + si._value );
}

template<class T>
void
Sample<T>::show(void)
{
    cout << _name << " = " << _value << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Sample<double> a("a"), b("b");
    a = 1; // Sample::operator=(const T&)
    b = 2.2; // Sample::operator=(const T&)
    a.show(); // Output: a = 1
    b.show(); // Output: b = 2.2

    auto c = a.makeNewObj("c"); // Should be possible
    c = a + b; // Sample::operator+(const Sample&) and Sample::operator=(const Sample&)
    c.show(); // Output: c = 3.2

//    Sample<double> d; // Compiler error as expected: undefined reference to `Sample::Sample()'
//    auto f = a; // Compiler error as expected: undefined reference to `Sample::Sample(Sample const&)'

    // This is what I want to avoid - should result in compiler error
    auto g = a+c; // No compiler error: uses the private constructor     Sample::Sample(const T&)
    g.show(); // Output: Temporary variable = 4.2  <-- !! Object with irrelevant name
}
```

Comment: AFAICT this has nothing to do with `auto`, but `Sample(Sample&&) = delete;` might solve your issue? (it will prevent creating `Sample` objects from temporary ones)

Comment: @Borgleader You are correct that `auto` is not the culprit (just writing `Sample<double>` has the same issue). However, deleting the move constructor does not help **in C++17** because both versions still compile (something something copy elision?), whereas deleting it in C++14 and lower does not help because then the posted `operator+` does not compile (uses move construction). Making the move constructor private solves it in the latter case.

Comment: André, which C++ version do you need this to work in?

Comment: @George It might be. The private constructor is needed for nested operations like `d = a + b + c`. The actual class has several other attributes other than name and value and the arithmetic operators would perform different checks before doing the actual operation. I figured avoiding the possibility of having meaningless objects would be a nice thing, but it might turn out not to be worth it. Anyway, I found the "problem" to be interesting and could not find a solution.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov No, see my comment above.

Comment: @MaxLanghof C++11, and newer if possible.

Comment: I would suggest, use a **different** type as a return type for your operations. For your original class, define an assignment operator which takes this type, but do not define constructor. Let me know if you need code.

Comment: Since C++17 requires return value optimization there's AFAIK no way you can prevent `T x = temporary();` from compiling.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov As @MaxLanghof pointed out, it may not work. But anyway, I still want to be able to use `auto` the deduce value type from an exiting variable. I will edit the question to include this.

Comment: @SergeyA This seems to be an reasonable solution. I will try to implement it myself. Anyway, I suggest you to write an answer with that, so I can accept it (once it works).

Comment: @AndréLucasChinazzo done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat related but also orthogonal to NathanOliver's answer:

You are mixing different concepts here. You have the notion of, essentially, `NamedValue` with `Sample`, but you are trying to make each *expression* formed out of arithmetics on `NamedValue` also a `NamedValue`. That is not going to work - the expression (by your semantics) does not have a name, so it should not be a `NamedValue`. Therefore, having `NamedValue operator+(const NamedValue& other)` is not meaningful.

Nathan's answer resolves this by making additions return `T` instead. That's pretty straightforward.

However, note that since `a + b` *must* have a type, you cannot stop `auto g = a + b` from compiling, even if it is demonstrably incorrect code. Ask [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html), or any other expression template library. This remains true no matter how you choose the return type of `operator+`. So this wish of yours cannot be granted, unfortunately.

Still, I would suggest that you don't use plain `T` as return type but rather another class, say, `Unnamed<T>`:

```
template<class T>
class Unnamed
{
public:
    explicit Unnamed(const T& value) : _value(value) {};

    Unnamed<T> operator+(const Unnamed<T>& rhs) const
    {
        return Unnamed<T>(_value + rhs._value);
    }

    friend Unnamed operator+(const Unnamed& lhs, const Sample<T>& rhs);
    friend Unnamed operator+(const Sample<T>& lhs, const Unnamed& rhs);

private:
    T _value;
};
```

This allows you to do your checks and what have you on every operation (because the middle `+` in `(a + b) + (c + d)` cannot accept `NamedValue`s, see above) instead of only when converting back to a named value.

[Demo here](https://godbolt.org/g/6tJwtT).

You can increase the compile-time safety slightly by only allowing construction of `Sample` from `Unnamed` temporaries: https://godbolt.org/g/Lpz1m5

This could all be done more elegantly than sketched here. Note that this is moving exactly in the direction of expression templates though.

Answer (score 6):

A quick workaround is to not return a temporary `Sample<T>` from `operator +`.  Since you only want the value part you can just return that instead. That changes the code to

```
T operator+(const Sample&) const;

template<class T>
T
Sample<T>::operator+(const Sample& si) const
{
    // if any of the two values are invalid, throw some error
    return  this->_value + si._value;
}
```

and then

```
auto g = a+c;
```

will make `g` whatever `T` is and `g.show();` will not compile as `g` isn't a `Sample<T>`.

```
Sample<double> g = a+c;
```

Will also not work as it tries to construct `g` from a value and that constructor is private.

---

This will require adding

```
friend T operator+(T val, Sample<T> rhs) { return val + rhs._value; }
```

If you want to be able to chain additions like

```
a + a + a;
```

Comment: This seems to be one good solution, but it relies on the call of other member functions (`g.show()`) to give a compiler error, an it will most probably result in an difficult to debug error.

Comment: @AndréLucasChinazzo At least gcc's error is pretty easy to deciper *error: request for member 'show' in 'g', which is of non-class type 'double'* So you a least know the compiler is treating `g` as something you didn't expect and can track that down.

Comment: True. I guess in most cases it would turn out to be enough. If no other member function is called (and therefore no compiler error), the overall result should be the same as if it was the right type. And tracking down the error should be easy enough, if you have any understanding of what you are coding.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to change the signature of the `+ operator` (or any other operation needs implemented) to return a different type.

Than add an assignment operator accepting this "different type", but do not add a copy constructor - alternatively, for better error reporting, add a `deleted` one.

This would require more coding, since you would probably want to define "operations" on this type as well, so that chaining works.